# Improved minimal webcrawler - why is it so slow?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping

I recently made a webcrawler that I submitted here for a review:

[Minimal webcrawler - bad structure and error handling?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49480/minimal-webcrawler-bad-structure-and-error-handling)

With that help, I've made a much cleaner and better(?) webcrawler.

The only problem I have is that this crawler is extremely slow compared to the other one (13.2s for a depth of 5, compared to 1.3s on the old solution).

Why is it so slow?
With cProfile I have gotten this [output over the 10 most time consuming functions](http://pastebin.com/wJypLgkQ). With depth 5, 57 links are crawled or scheduled for crawling - while is_valid_link are called 243 times. Could there be some errors in that method?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import httplib
import urlparse
import urllib2
import time

def sanitize(url, parent):
    if is_internal_link(url):
        if parent.endswith("/") or url.startswith("/"):
            return parent + url
        else:
            return parent + "/" + url
    return url

def is_internal_link(url):
    if url.startswith("http"):
        return False
    return True

def hostname(link):
    hostname = urlparse.urlparse(link).hostname
    return hostname

def get_server_status_code(link):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140661
    host, path = urlparse.urlparse(link)[1:3]
    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
        conn.request('HEAD', path)
        return conn.getresponse().status
    except StandardError:
        return None

def is_valid_link(link):
    link = sanitize(link, hostname(urlsToCrawl_Parent[0]))
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924422
    good_codes = [httplib.OK, httplib.FOUND, httplib.MOVED_PERMANENTLY]
    return get_server_status_code(link) in good_codes

def fetch_webpage(url):
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return webpage

def fetch_links(webpage):
    html = webpage.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    links = soup.find_all("a", href=True)
    return links

def schedule_link(link):
    if is_valid_link(link):    
        if hostname(link) in urlsToCrawl_Parent[0]:
            urlsToCrawl_Parent.append(link)
    else:
        urlsToCrawl_Child.append(link)

def havent_visited(link):
    if link not in urls_Crawled and link not in urlsToCrawl_Parent and link not in urlsToCrawl_Child:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def crawl(url):
    webpage = fetch_webpage(url)
    links = fetch_links(webpage)
    for link in links:
        link = link['href'] 
        #This is not done on a good way at all, should clearly do this in fetch_links?
        if havent_visited(link):
            schedule_link(link)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls_Crawled = []
    urlsToCrawl_Parent = []
    urlsToCrawl_Child = []

    urlsToCrawl_Parent.append("STARTLINK")
    while (len(urls_Crawled) < 5):
        if (len(urlsToCrawl_Parent) > 0):
            crawl(urlsToCrawl_Parent[0])
            urls_Crawled.append(urlsToCrawl_Parent[0])
            urlsToCrawl_Parent.pop(0)

        elif (len(urlsToCrawl_Child) > 0):
            urlsToCrawl_Parent.append(urlsToCrawl_Child[0])
            crawl(urlsToCrawl_Parent[0])
            urls_Crawled.append(urlsToCrawl_Parent[0])
            urlsToCrawl_Parent.pop(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling it to find out where the time is taken?

Comment: I have just checked that there isn't any methods where the program stalls. I've also tried some print statements where i print the urls processed, and i get a steady flow of urls.

**Edit:** I googled profiling python, and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) I will try that, thanks

Comment: I would suggest you profile both code and see which part is now slower.

Comment: Try something more structured, e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: I've profiled with cProfile and sorted the output after total cummulative time and this is the result:

http://pastebin.com/wJypLgkQ

The depth is 5, and the total crawled links and links scheduled for crawling is 57, while is_valid_link is called 243 times - to many links stated as unvalid?

Comment: @Bjornasm: You can edit the question to include the profile results.

Comment: @unholysampler: See my edited answer for some analysis based on the profile results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

Analysis of posted profile results

Of all the functions listed in the result, your code accounts for `0.041` seconds. However, the cumulative time for the entire execution is `14.169`. This has your code accounting for `.289%` of the entire execution.

The function that takes the most time is the `recv()` calls on the underlying sockets. This one function is dominating the execution time compared to any of the other functions. From this we see that transferring files over the internet is very slow. Evaluating a boolean expression and manipulating a list is very fast.

Based on the analysis, we have learned that your program's bottleneck is the IO over the network. Every time your code reads a new html file, nothing else is happening in your application. What you can do to speed this is up is to execute code in parallel so that you a reading in multiple files at one time. You can look into [threads](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html) to do this type of parallelization. However, by doing this you will also have to synchronize access `ToCrawl` and `Crawled` lists.

---

**Original**:

A review of the code independent of an performance considerations.

---

```
def hostname(link):
    hostname = urlparse.urlparse(link).hostname
    return hostname
```

Your variable is hiding the function name. Doing this in a function that is meant to be recursive would lead to an error. Instead you can return the value directly instead of creating a local variable.

There are a few other places you create a local variable and only reference them once. Sometimes giving a value a name can increase readability. However, most of the code in this post do not fit into this category.

---

```
def is_internal_link(url):
    if url.startswith("http"):
        return False
    return True
```

`startswith()` is already returning a boolean. You don't need the if statement to explicitly return the result.

```
def is_internal_link(url):
    return not url.startswith("http")
```

---

Another example if using an if statement to explicitly return a boolean.

```
def havent_visited(link):
    if link not in urls_Crawled and link not in urlsToCrawl_Parent and link not in urlsToCrawl_Child:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I point this out because it is done in a different style. This explicitly uses an `else` where as the first case used the implicit else as the true clause will always exit the function. Using a standard convention throughout the code base will improve readability. In this case, one style is not better, but you should be consistent.

---

```
crawl(urlsToCrawl_Parent[0])
urls_Crawled.append(urlsToCrawl_Parent[0])
urlsToCrawl_Parent.pop(0)
```

is equivalent to

```
target = urlsToCrawl_Parent.pop(0)
crawl(target)
urls_Crawled.append(target)
```

The second version is cleaner because the variable name gives you context. You also don't have to worry about indexing the list multiple times.

The `elif` block is also executing this same operation. You can more this repeated code into a function.

---

```
while (len(urls_Crawled) < 5):
```

`5` is a magic number here. There is no context to why a number less than `5` is important. If there is another `5` somewhere else in the code, does it mean the same thing? Giving a constant a name will provide this context. Also, if you need to change it later, you will just have to change the code in one place. And you won't have to worry about that other `5` that had a different context.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, I must note that I only included the 10 most time consuming functions in pastebin, but I think that doesn't inflict  your answer. The strange thing is that I use urllib to open a webpage, as i did in my [previous solution](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49480/minimal-webcrawler-bad-structure-and-error-handling)

Shouldn't they have the same IO - or is the old solution serialized by a stroke of luck?

Comment: @Bjornasm: In both cases you are handling a single page at a time and reading the entire file into a string right after opening the url. I wouldn't expect one to perform much faster than the other. However, now that you know how to use the profiler, it would be straight forward to try swapping in `urllib2`. However, you are still going to deal with all the external variance that is reading files over the internet. A different idea would be to test with `file://` urls and process files that are all stored locally on your machine.